# Create/Edit subclass templates in XCode 4+

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, templates, uiviewcontroller

I've edited the templates in earlier versions of XCode, but I can't figure out how to do it with XCode 4+, since the directories are completely different.

Do I still navigate to the subclass template directory and edit the file? If so, what is the path to find the files?

If not, what can I do to edit them?

Thank you for reading this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I've figured it out. You can create a custom directory in `~/Library/Developer/XCode/Templates/File Templates` for customizing subclasses.